# c# Linq Object subQuery / In

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have 2 objects that contains generic list properties.
IE :

```
public class User
{
    public string Sid { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public string Sid { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

From my BLL I get a generic list of sections 
List mySections=SectionDB.getList();

and my User object contains the user Information
User myUser=UserDB.getInfo(sid);

Using linq to objects, is it possible to make a query that retreives all the sections where there is at least one group within the groups user class?

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from section in mySections
from sectionGroup in section.Groups
where myUser.Groups.Any(userGroup => userGroup == sectionGroup)
select section
```

i'd rather go for any, as you use the iterator much more efficiently

Comment: as long as you work on the exact same reference... like marc said ... otherwise you can include a Func<Group, bool> in your .Any()-call to get eg. check for ids. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx

Comment: I'm a bit curious how to use the Func<Group,bool) using the Mark's method.
Anyway I thank you all

Comment: eg. `.Any(userGroup => userGroup.Id == sectionGroup.Id)` - you can also instatiate your `IEqualityComparer<Group>` and do sth like `.Any(userGroup => myInstanceOfMyComparer.Equals(userGroup, sectionGroup))`. another method would be to implement `IEquatable<Group>` on `Group`

Answer (score 2):

```
var sections = mySections.Where(x => x.Groups.Intersect(myUser.Groups)
    .Any()).ToList();
```

(note that this relies on either referential equality of the `Group` instances, or a suitable `Equals` / `GetHashCode` implementation on the `Group` type)

Comment: @Marc: I always learn something from you. Like till today I never noticed the 'parameterless' `Any` method  :)